# How do I accommodate for Structural Break in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have time series data for hot dog sales, and I have a quadratic regression that includes monthly seasonal dummy variables.

```
sales.ts        = ts(data=hotdog, start=c(1987,1), frequency=12)
mond            = seasonaldummy(sales.ts)
Dec             = matrix(data=rep(c(rep(0,11),1),28), nrow=336, ncol=1)
time            = data.frame(c(1:336))
q.seas          = data.frame(cbind(hotdog, time, I(time^2), mond, Dec))
quad.seas.sales = lm(hotdog~.-1, data=q.seas)
```

I've used sctest to detect structural break, and I have a very small p-value, which indicates structural change.

I'm not sure how to find out where the break occurs, and how to use dummy variables to accommodate for the structural break.

Comment: You can use the `breakpoints()` function for that, see the manual page and associated references for some worked examples.

Comment: When I use breakpoints(hotdog~.1,data=q.seas), I get an error: Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to specify the regressors explicitly (not with ".").